# Groovy script is failing to remove the space from the result sampler in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

So I have built a customized listener(using groovy script) to post my result to influxdb but the current script is failing when there is a white space in the `sampler name or transaction controller name`.

Tried to put a fail safe(this will remove the space from the sampler result) in my script but it is not working

groovy script sample in the listener,

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;

try {

Metrics = new StringBuilder();
 String status = "Failure";
  if (sampleResult.isSuccessful())
      status = "Success";
 if (sampleResult.getSampleLabel().startsWith("/"))
      Metrics.append("Requests")
 else
 Metrics.append("JMeter_Result")
 Metrics.append(",requestName=")
 .append(escapeValue(sampleResult.getSampleLabel()))
 .append(",httpstatuscode=")
 .append(sampleResult.getResponseCode())
 .append(",status=")
 .append(status)
 .append(",ScenarioID=")
 .append('${__groovy(vars.get("uniqueScenario_Id"),)}')
 .append(" responseTime=")
 .append(sampleResult.getTime())
 .append(",responsecode=")
 .append("\"${(sampleResult.getResponseCode())}\"")
 .append(",sentBytes=")
 .append(sampleResult.getSentBytes())
 .append(",receivedBytes=")
 .append(sampleResult.getBytesAsLong())
 .append( ",responseMessage=")
 .append("\"${(sampleResult.getResponseMessage())}\"")
 .append(",samplecount=")
 .append(sampleResult.getSampleCount())
 .append(",errorCount=")
 .append(sampleResult.getErrorCount())
 .append(" ")
 .append(sampleResult.getTimeStamp())
 .append("000000");
     if(sampleResult.getSampleLabel().equals("UserIdleTime"))
        {
        }
    else {
        PostMeasurement(Metrics.toString());
        }
} catch (Exception e) {
     log.error("Error in Grafana Metrics Listener : " +e );
}
//Escape the string values before posting the data
String escapeValue(String val) {
 val = val.replaceAll(",", "\\\\,")
 .replaceAll(" ", "\\\\")
 .replaceAll("=", "\\\\=")
 .trim();
    if(val.matches(".*\\s.*")) {
        val = val.replaceAll("\\s","");
        return val;
    }
    else {
        return val;
    }
 // return val;

}

// Post the result to influxDB
void PostMeasurement(String Metrics) {
 def httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
 def httpPost = new HttpPost();
 httpPost.setURI(new URI(vars.get("InfluxDBAPI")));
 httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(Metrics));
 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
 EntityUtils.consumeQuietly(response.getEntity());
}
```

Transaction Controller Name [with space]:

[image]

Failing With Error:
[image]

Transaction Controller Name [without space]:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following function:

```
static String removeWhiteSpaces(String input) {
    return input.replaceAll(~/\s/, '')
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Also be informed that

1. JSR223 Listener is being executed **after each Sampler** in its scope so your approach will be resource intensive and might have an impact on your test results. You might want to consider using your own implementation of the [AbstractBackendListenerClient](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/visualizers/backend/AbstractBackendListenerClient.html). See [How to Develop a JMeter Plugin: Intro & Best Practices](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugin-development) article for more details.
2. The functionality of storing test metrics into InfluxDB is there already, check out [Real-time results](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html) JMeter documentation chapter
3. I don't like this construction: `${__groovy(vars.get("uniqueScenario_Id"),)}`, as per [JSR223 Sampler Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

   > When using this feature, ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code as caching would only cache first replacement. Instead use script parameters.

   so if your `uniqueScenario_Id` may change during script execution only first occurrence will be cached and returned on subsequent executions.

Comment: Thanks I will try and check, `uniqueScenario_Id` will be constant per execution which is going to help me to compare the result in grafana

Comment: Which is work as per my requirement for `uniqueScenario_Id`

Comment: Thank you it worked, I have similar concern of this listener and I am thinking to implement a batch to handle the extreme load